# Nifi UpdateAttribute not working for dynamic variable

Tags: apache-nifi, kylo

I am trying to get the count of files processed by ListHDFS, so the flow looks like this:

ListHDFS -> UpdateAttribute -> LogAttribute

I configured UpdateAttribute as per documentation (see attachment). Strangely, I am not even seeing "fileCount" in "view data provenance" option.

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to see fileCount attribute value as 1 in data provenance,

I have recreated your scenario as

```
Generateflowfile --> UpdateAttribute --> LogAttribute
```

***UpdateAttribute configs:***

**fileCount**
`${getStateValue("fileCount"):plus(1)}`

Stateful Variables Initial Value
0

***Provenance for the file:***
[image]

Initial value for the **fileCount** attribute is **null(no value)** and in **UpdateAttribute** we are adding one to the **fileCount** attribute and the **new value is 1**.